# Laravel 6 Prevent restricted actions which are registered after logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm using `laravel/ui` for authentication, let's say i opened my website in two separate tabs.

After i logout from one tab, if i click let's say delete blog button on other tab,

it takes me to login page as i'm using auth middleware, after which if i login and my delete action runs.

How to prevent this, i only want delete action to run when user is logged in and in the above case, after user logs in, i don't want to perform delete action straight away, user needs to click delete button again.

Comment: What type of request GET, POST, or DELETE your delete action uses?

Comment: Check Auth user Login before the Delete

Comment: Make sure your delete route has the Auth middleware assigned: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Comment: @EriksKlotins just using anchor tag, request is GET

Comment: @Periplo i am using middleware in my controller, that's not the problem, it's doing it's job, it takes me to login page when i click delete, the problem is if i login with same credentials it will delete it, even if someone else other than me has clicked the delete button, it queue the delete action and performs 
it immediately after i login, it should either confirm or discard the queue entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1. The best practice would be to change the delete request type to POST. [Check here how to correctly use HTTP methods](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/)
2. In your Auth middleware, always redirect the user to some landing page.

I would strongly advise changing the request type. Once, I had to help to restore an IT system where some smart arse ran script to follow all links in an internal website and fetch all pages. Delete operations were implemented with the GET method.